# Nodejs With Snap

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, snapcraft

I had installed nodejs -v 13 from snapcraft store. And, now I want to remove that node version and switch to lower version. Here, I am wondering How to remove it, since "sudo apt-get purge nodejs" or "sudo apt-get remove nodejs" seem not working.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using snap to install nodjs you need to either remove it from Ubuntu Software or snap store, you can find both in default application in ubuntu. or from command line -

```
sudo snap remove node /sudo snap remove nodejs
```

If you have to constantly change nodejs version I recommend using NVM (Node version management) which lets install and node version with simple command line commands. To install NVM/Nodejs use this reference link - [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04) -> How to install using NVM.

NVM and NPM are must have packages when you work with nodejs.

Hop this helps.